Getting this error "ENOTEEMPTY" even though I tried deleting and reinstalling node_modules several times
first let me give you a little brief about my system. I am using Linux Mint alongside Windows 10 (dual boot), just saying because perhaps it might be relevant with the error I am facing.
Previously I started developing an app using expo SDK version 50, and everything was going smoothly. I did a lot of works in the app. Then for about 2-3 months, I couldn't work in the app. I was using a custom font called "Gabarito".
Now, when I wanted to work again on the project, I updated expo go to the latest version and it asked me to update expo sdk to version 51. I was facing some issues with updating expo so someone suggested me to delete node_modules folder and reinstall all the dependencies using npm install. I did so and it turned out to be fine. Then I thought of changing my font to "HindSiliguri". Now this is how my app.js looks like:
const [fontsLoaded, fontError] = useFonts({
    "HindSiliguri-Regular": require("./assets/fonts/HindSiliguri-Regular.ttf"),
    "HindSiliguri-Bold": require("./assets/fonts/HindSiliguri-Bold.ttf"),
    "HindSiliguri-Light": require("./assets/fonts/HindSiliguri-Light.ttf"),
    "HindSiliguri-Medium": require("./assets/fonts/HindSiliguri-Medium.ttf"),
    "HindSiliguri-SemiBold": require("./assets/fonts/HindSiliguri-SemiBold.ttf"),
  });

useEffect(() => {
    async function handleLayout() {
      if (fontsLoaded && initialScreen) {
        await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
      }
    }
    handleLayout();
  }, [fontsLoaded, initialScreen]);

  if (!fontsLoaded || !initialScreen) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>App loading, please have patience.</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }


There are some more codes that ensures that my font is completely loaded. When I open the app, the font works. Still I get the following warning:
fontFamily "HindSiliguri-Bold" is not a system font and has not been loaded through expo-font.
But the font is perfectly working in the app. Another error I am getting is:-
fontFamily "anticon" is not a system font and has not been loaded through expo-font. 
But I am not using any font called "anticon". Someone told me to install expo-font. so I tried to install that library (I had it installed previously but tried to reinstall) using this command npx expo install expo-font
And now I am getting this error:
› Installing 1 SDK 51.0.0 compatible native module using npm
> npm install
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /media/araf/New Volume3/Vakwita/Projects/Prose/node_modules/ajv
npm ERR! dest /media/araf/New Volume3/Vakwita/Projects/Prose/node_modules/.ajv-xJT1TTpP
npm ERR! errno -39
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/media/araf/New Volume3/Vakwita/Projects/Prose/node_modules/ajv' -> '/media/araf/New Volume3/Vakwita/Projects/Prose/node_modules/.ajv-xJT1TTpP'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/araf/.npm/_logs/2024-06-06T12_18_04_833Z-debug-0.log
Error: npm install exited with non-zero code: 217
Error: npm install exited with non-zero code: 217

If I try to delete the folder called ajv then it throws the same error with a different folder. And if I delete that too then another error comes with another different folder.
I again deleted node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstalled using npm install. Still facing the same issue. I tried this several times.
What I already tried to resolve this:

delete node_modules folder
delete package-lock.json
run npm update
npm cache clear --force
npm install --save
sudo npm install
various combinations of the above

